# Accuracy and performance between a division and subtraction for a ratio in decibels

Tags: floating-point, performance, numerical-analysis

For comparing two images, one can use the Peak Signal-to-Noise Ratio (PSNR) metric, defined as follows:

$\mathrm{PSNR} = 10 \cdot \log_{10}\left(\frac{\mathrm{MAX}^2}{\mathrm{MSE}}\right) = 20 \cdot \log_{10}(\mathrm{MAX}) - 10 \cdot \log_{10}(\mathrm{MSE})\ dB.$

with $\mathrm{MAX}$ being the maximum gray-scale value ($2^8-1 = 255$ in my case), and $\mathrm{MSE}$ being the mean squared error.

My question is, among the definition with division ($\mathrm{PSNR}_{\div}$) and subtraction ($\mathrm{PSNR}_{-}$), which one is the most numerically accurate? And which one is the most computationally efficient?

I made an experiment with MATLAB R2015a, and for some MSE values, I have different scores. For instance, knowing that the machine epsilon is $\epsilon = 2.2204e{-16}$, for $\mathrm{MSE} = 1708.25$ and $\mathrm{MSE} = 1710.00$, I have $\left| \mathrm{PSNR}_{\div} - \mathrm{PSNR}_{-} \right| = 1.42109e-14$ and $7.10543e-15$ respectively. What can I conclude?

Note: in $\mathrm{PSNR}_{-}$, $20 \cdot \log_{10}(\mathrm{MAX})$ can be reduced to a pre-computed constant.

Comment: One aspect of your question is numerical analysis, which should be on-topic here. As for what is more efficient on particular hardware, this seems off-topic; also, the simple answer is what you've already done – time both options.

Comment: I am interested in answers, ranging from the mathematical to hardware aspects. If the numerical analysis is on-topic, it is a good start! However, I do not understand why floating-point instructions are off-topic? It is not always easy to choose the appropriate StackExchange network for such complex questions. But I am not sure that the mathematical aspects can be separated to the hardware ones for a precise answer.

Comment: Answers pertaining to particular architectures are typically off-topic here.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my question.

Comment: Note that I did not monitored the time for both options. I actually checked the absolute difference between the numerical results given by both options.

Comment: But you could also monitor the time.

Comment: I could, but will it be meaningful? It seems that there are so many parameters: the optimizations made by a given compiler, the logarithm implementation, the floating-point instructions being used, etc. Monitoring the time will not explain why is one faster than the other?

Comment: For exactly these reasons, the best way to see which way is better is to try both. There's really no reason to attempt a theoretical analysis.